# How do you make biber optional when compiling using vs code

Tags: luatex, compiling, biber, vscode, latex-workshop

So I wanted to compile using lualatex for the compiler and biber for bibliography management.  So I decided to have this in my JSON settings file:

```
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "lualatex->biber->lualatex",
            "tools": [
                "lualatex",
                "biber",
                "lualatex"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "lualatex",
            "command": "lualatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

The problem is that when I press the compile button, when it got to biber it stops compiling and shows this error message:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'main.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'main.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

What do I do? Do I have to have a blank bibliography file with every project? Is there something I can do to make this biber part optional?